# Quartic equation problem in Maple

Tags: maple, quartics

I'm having this problem when trying to solve this equation in Maple.

$f(x) = x^{4}-27.9000678$

[Here's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KsAn.png)

Each time i try to run the solve command Maple returns me this weird answer: `proc (x) 1/10*RootOf(500*_Z^4-139500339,label = _L3) end proc`

Is this related to my software or could it be a bug within the program? Can you experts please help me to bypass this or suggest me an alternate solution?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with how you have `f` declared. If you want `f` to be a function, use:

```
f := x -> x^4 - 27.9000678;
solve(f(x)=0,x);
```

This returns:

```
2.298271411, 2.298271411*I, -2.298271411, -2.298271411*I
```

Otherwise if you use your code (where `f` is declared as a variable) then the following will work:

```
f:=x^4-27.9000678;
solve(f=0,x);
```

Comment: Thanks that was of much help.